# AngularJS Variable From Server Side

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, webforms

I'm writing an ASP.NET application with AngularJS. I have a value that can only be accessed from the codebehind of a page. I'd like to pass this value down so it can be used by an AngularJS controller. I know it's possible to grab URL parameters for use in AngularJS, but I haven't been able to find any other way of getting a value into my controller. Is this possible?

For example, if I have a setup like this:

```
<%= user.UserDescription %> <%-- this is how I'd get my value from the codebehind --%>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myController1'></div>
...
</div>
```

I want `myController1` to have access to `user.UserDescription`. It's obviously possible to place the value anywhere on the page, by embedding the C# in the ASP.NET page as you see above, but is it possible to pass it into the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue as I had sever side config that I wanted the client side application to know. The solution I came up with is was a config constant that I would add to the bottom of the page. Then loaded that into my services, etc....

Something like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        ....
    </head>
    ....

    <body>
        <script>
            (function(){
              'use strict';
              angular.module('myapp.config',[])
                .constant('CONFIG', {
                  user: {
                        description: '<%= user.UserDescription %>'
                    }
                });
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Then how can you call that from the controller without it yelling at you that it doesn't exist?

Comment: Without knowing that, it seems to just be "undefined" when called from any controller.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/OgsNzAHhW7shaf4yVVaf?p=preview simple example of what I am referring to.